# laravel mysql query joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, function, laravel-5

I have two tables

```
--------------
Categories
--------------
id
category

--------------
Products
--------------
id
category
product details
```

I need to get join the both categories and get the `product details` according to the `category id` please help to build the query in laravel

I tried this but didn't work

```
$shares = \DB::table('products')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.category', '=', 'products.category')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('categories.id', '=', $id)
        ->get();
```

im getting an error which is

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array** is a self explanatory error, it means some where in your code you are trying to use an object like array.

Comment: can you post the line which is throwing the error

Comment: @jayasinkar       public function getAllCategorymen($id){

        $shares = \DB::table('products')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.category', '=', 'products.category')
            ->select('*')
            ->where('categories.id', '=', $id)
            ->get();
        return view('shop.allCategorymen', ['shares' => $shares]);
    }

Comment: error is in controller or view ? If you could post the stack trace

Comment: your above function seems ok. Error might be somewhere else

Comment: This is my view

Comment: this is my view
    @foreach($shares->chunk(6) as $productChunk)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($productChunk as $product)
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">

                    <div class="panel text-center w3-card-2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">

Comment: do a `var_dump($shares)` and `var_dump($productChunk)` in your view to check they are actually collections

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$shares = \App\Product::select('*')
        ->join('Category', function ($join) {
            $join->on('categories.category', '=','products.category');
        })->where('categories.id',$id)
        ->get();
```